# I want to put "" around %r output

Tags: python-2.7

```
hilarious = False

joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! %r"

print joke_evaluation % hilarious
```

For this code, I tried `"Isn't that joke so funny?! "%r\" "`

But I don't get an output for `%r`.  If I use single quotes around `%r` it works, however how do I do `""`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to maintain the double quotes in your output, I think you need to escape the double quotes in the joke_evaluation string variable.

joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! %r"

becomes:

joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! \"%r\""

>>>print joke_evaluation % hilarious

Isn't that joke so funny?! "False"

Hope that helps.

Comment: Or use triple quotes; that's what they are for. `joke = """Isn't that joke hilarious? "%r""""`